# Add to string on button click WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF following an attempt to move from winforms so this is basic question however i'm trying to add to a string from a button click. The scenario is basically a keypad full of buttons (0 - 9) and the user presses these as to enter a code as a type of PIN. The method of going about this is non-negotiable so i cannot just replace with a text box and have the user type this. I have a little knowledge on bindings however it appears to be the appending to a string which is throwing me out as, obviously, all the buttons (0-9) need to be able to append to this string in sequence. So anyway, i have a ViewModel with a property called 'EnteredCode' and the buttons reside in a grid named 'buttonsGrid'. Would i be correct in thinking i handle the ButtonBase.Click event at the Grid level, determine which one was clicked and then append to the string? The appending to the string is obviously the problem here which i need help with but just as general feedback to best practise!

Code examples would also be a huge help.

TIA

Comment: You mention ViewModel. Are you trying to do MVVM? If so you wouldn't be using the Button.Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can treat WPF just as windows forms and solve this in the codebehind MainWindow.xaml.cs
Example:

```
    DemonstrationViewModel demoViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        demoViewModel = new DemonstrationViewModel();
        DataContext = demoViewModel;
    }

    private void alsoDemoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        demoViewModel.EnteredCode += "Clicked";
    }
```

However, with the mention of ViewModel in your statement, you are likely following a MVVM pattern and writing in the code behind is not recommended.

If you are following a MVVM pattern, ICommands would be one way to go.

Pseudocode-ish example

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="demoButton" Command="{Binding InsertCommand}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
    #region Constructor
    public DemonstrationViewModel()
    {
        InsertCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteInsert, CanExecuteInsert);
    }
    #endregion

    private void ExecuteInsert()
    {
        EnteredCode += "Clicked! ";
    }
```

[Further reading on ICommand in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example)

Comment: A much simpler example to the one above and the further reading helped solve the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to bind Password property of PasswordBox to your ViewModel property. Password property is not bindable as it is not a DependencyProperty. This is for security reasons.

However if you want to make it bindable, you have to use a custom AttachedProperty. Now, you are trying to input PIN by pressing buttons like in ATM machines, and want your password bindable too. See a sample below to get you started.

xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfEvents._32802407.Win32802407"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:pwd="clr-namespace:PasswordExtras"
        Title="Win32802407" Height="354.136" Width="385.714">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="143*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="46*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome Joshua !" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,4,0,4"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="pbPin" pwd:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True" pwd:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=PIN, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72">
            <Button Content="Done" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="31"/>
            <Button Content="Clear" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="31"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="31"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel ButtonBase.Click="NumericButtons_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="147" Margin="10,23,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266">
            <Button Content="1" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="2" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="3" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="4" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="5" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="6" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="7" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="8" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="9" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
            <Button Content="0" Width="75" Margin="5" Height="25"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,9,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter your pin or press cancel" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

xaml code-behind :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfEvents._32802407
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32802407.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32802407 : Window
    {
        ViewModelATM atm =  new ViewModelATM();
        public Win32802407()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = atm;
        }

        private void NumericButtons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string pwd = PasswordExtras.PasswordBoxAssistant.GetBoundPassword(pbPin);

            if (pwd.Length == 4)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }

            pwd = pwd + ((Button)e.OriginalSource).Content;

            PasswordExtras.PasswordBoxAssistant.SetBoundPassword(pbPin, pwd);

            Debug.WriteLine(pwd + " : " + atm.PIN);
        }
    }
}

namespace PasswordExtras
{
  public static class PasswordBoxAssistant
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPassword =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPassword = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "BindPassword", typeof (bool), typeof (PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindPasswordChanged));

      private static readonly DependencyProperty UpdatingPassword =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdatingPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false));

      private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          PasswordBox box = d as PasswordBox;

          // only handle this event when the property is attached to a PasswordBox
          // and when the BindPassword attached property has been set to true
          if (d == null || !GetBindPassword(d))
          {
              return;
          }

          // avoid recursive updating by ignoring the box's changed event
          box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;

          string newPassword = (string)e.NewValue;

          if (!GetUpdatingPassword(box))
          {
              box.Password = newPassword;
          }

          box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
      }

      private static void OnBindPasswordChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          // when the BindPassword attached property is set on a PasswordBox,
          // start listening to its PasswordChanged event

          PasswordBox box = dp as PasswordBox;

          if (box == null)
          {
              return;
          }

          bool wasBound = (bool)(e.OldValue);
          bool needToBind = (bool)(e.NewValue);

          if (wasBound)
          {
              box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;
          }

          if (needToBind)
          {
              box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
          }
      }

      private static void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          PasswordBox box = sender as PasswordBox;

          // set a flag to indicate that we're updating the password
          SetUpdatingPassword(box, true);
          // push the new password into the BoundPassword property
          SetBoundPassword(box, box.Password);
          SetUpdatingPassword(box, false);
      }

      public static void SetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
      {
          dp.SetValue(BindPassword, value);
      }

      public static bool GetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          return (bool)dp.GetValue(BindPassword);
      }

      public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPassword);
      }

      public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
      {
          dp.SetValue(BoundPassword, value);
      }

      private static bool GetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          return (bool)dp.GetValue(UpdatingPassword);
      }

      private static void SetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
      {
          dp.SetValue(UpdatingPassword, value);
      }
  }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;

namespace WpfEvents._32802407
{
    public class ViewModelATM 
    {
        string _pin = "";
        public string PIN { get { return _pin; } set { _pin = value; } }

    }
}
```

Comment: A very nice answer however i think it's a little overkill for the task in hand,  although the examples on attach properties also helped!

Comment: It's not an overkill, I have posted complete sample solution because you asked for sample code. You need Attached Property for PasswordBox, and also you need Binding too. You also said in your question that you want to handle Button clicks. Solution is posted based on your requirements.